# Is it possible for a graph to have two different minimum spanning tree

Tags: graphs, spanning-trees

I am suppose to create a minimum spanning tree from this graph below

[image]

I got this answer

[image]

However this is my textbook answer

[image]

Based on what i have learnt , I think my answer and the textbook answer would both be acceptable however I would like assurance from the community that both the answers are acceptable and I did not miss anything out

Thanks

Comment: Both of those appear to be minimum spanning trees, yes. Does the book say that you should use a specific algorithm to calculate the tree? If so, you should check carefully whether that algorithm would produce your tree or the book's. If the book doesn't specify an algorithm, then including an exercise with two answers but only printing one of those answers is a small error in the book.

Comment: If you obtain a) a spanning tree with b) the same (minimal) total weight as the textbook solution, why do you doubt?

Answer (score 12):

It is possible to have different minimum spanning trees for a graph. 
Consider a simple example: a [cycle graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_graph) with all weights equal. Removing any edge from the graph produces a minimum spanning tree for the cycle graph.